# Return 3 closest locations to a users location (geolocation) and list those locations for them

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-fusion-tables

### Background:

I am working on a website/app built with HTML/CSS/Javascript that will use geolocation (Google Maps API) to find a users location (geolocation) and return them, for example, the top 5 closest water parks to them at that location they are currently at so they will be able to then navigate to one of those locations. I am using Google Fusion Tables to return the results to them.

### Question:

I have been able to successfully...

- Find the users location and put a marker there (using Map API/geolocation)
- Return 3 out of 5 locations and put markers down for those 3 (I used Fusion Tables & limited results to 3)

I want to be able to…

1. Return only the **3 closest locations** to the user (i.e. calculate distance from users location to nearest water park)
2. Put a "sidebar" or **list of those 3 locations**, detailing name, address, and other fields in my Fusion Table

I made a Fiddle below this code with what I have so far. The code below is my Fusion Table query, which I assume is what I will need to make the changes to in order to get the 3 closest locations (question #1). Question #2, listing those locations, might use all of the code I have in my Fiddle.

```
var base_query = {
    select: 'Location',
    from: '1MsmdOvWLKNNrtKnmoEf2djCc3Rp_gYmueN4FGnc',
    limit: 3
};

var ftLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    query: $.extend({}, base_query)
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < base_query.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(base_query[i][1], base_query[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(base_query[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
};

var signChange = function () {
    var options = {
        query: $.extend({}, base_query)
    };
};
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/bRLaH/2/**

Any help would be appreciated. I have been doing research on this question for some time, but for whatever reason I am not able to piece it all together. Any help/resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will need to query the FusionTable using either [GViz](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) or the [Fusion Tables API v1.0](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using) to retrieve the data to put in the sidebar. ([example with sidebar using GViz](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html). [another example with sidebar using GViz](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_AfricaMap_kml_sidebar.html))

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this. I actually came across your site the other day, somehow I missed the most important examples.

Comment: @geocodezip - do you happen to have any examples on your site that deal with calculating the distance from the users position to the nearest point(s) that get returned from my Fusion Tables and also write out the distance (i.e. 10 miles away, 20 miles away, etc.)? I assume it is a JSONP request. I have a Github project now if you want to view any code - (https://github.com/jamez14/TrailFinder) - thank you!!

Comment: @geocodezip I was able to successfully get the 3 closest locations. Now I just need to get their distance/mileage away from the users location. If you happen to have time to help, that'd be great. I appreciate it!!

Comment: Like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlaces.html)?

Comment: Yes - that looks like it contains some pieces that will definitely get me going. I believe the `codeAddress()` and subsequent functions will hopefully mesh well with my existing code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related to 1. (2. has been answered in the comments by geocodezip)

Use a spatial_relationship in the `orderBy`-option of `base_query`.

```
orderBy: 'ST_DISTANCE(Coordinates, LATLNG(lat,lng))
```

...where `lat` and `lng` has to be populated with the values returned by `navigator.geolocation`(what means that you must create the layer or at least set the query for the layer in the callback of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`)

Comment: Just to clarify, should I be setting the `lat` and `lng` in the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {`or putting them elsewhere to make them globally available?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but they must be visible in the scope where you set the query for the layer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the numerous questions, but for whatever reason I'm having a tough time with this Fusion query. Anyway, I made another Fiddle using your advice and it doesn't seem to be limiting my returned results. Maybe it's bad data on my end? I've done a bit of research and wasn't able to find any helpful resources. I made lat & lng globally available also: http://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/DteSj/ if you have time to answer additional questions I'd appreciate it!

Comment: There are 2 issues: **1.** geolocating is an asynchronous process, you can't set the query for the layer(which requires `lat` and `lng` from geolocation) before the success-callback of `getCurrentPosition` has been executed. So the best would be to move the code that creates the layer to the success-callback. **2:** you must use a string concatenation, otherwise the values of `lat` and `lng` will not be applied to the orderBy. **`'ST_DISTANCE(Coordinates, LATLNG('+lat+','+lng+')'`**  . Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/eUGFV/

Comment: additionally: you better initially set a default-center for the map. Firefox will not execute the error-callback of `getCurrentPosition` when the user denies access to geolocation, in this case the map never would be rendered because of the missing(but required) center-property of the map.

Comment: Great - thank you again so much for the extra help! I really, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Places API.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Supported location types: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

After you have recieved the users location, make a request like that with your location and relevant types:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

---

Here is a fiddle based on yours, without using fusion tables:
http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/M9KrK/

Add this to your libary call:

```
&libraries=places
```

Add this to your code:

Global var:

```
var service;
```

If statement when you found the users location:

```
var request = { location: pos, radius: '500', types: ['store'] };

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

After maps init:

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

   function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  }); 
}
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Example with sidebar + FT usage from @geocodezip: http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html

Comment: I will certainly test this approach out tomorrow morning. After reading through some of the Places API, do you think this is a better approach than Fusion Tables?

Comment: If the data you are looking for is in the Places API, it is certainly simpler. But be sure to look at your projected usage as well.  If the date isn't in the Places API or even if _some_ of the data isn't in the Places API, you will have to deal with that, if you put the data in a Fusion Table, you have control.

Comment: I think that is where my problem is with the Places API. It doesn't contain the data I need - and having all the control via Fusion Tables seems like the best route to go. I'll definitely keep this in mind though for future reference. Thank you both!